# Python multiprocessing: call module with multiprocessing from another script with passing variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a module `multy.py` with simple example of using multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])
    print result.get(timeout=1) 
    print pool.map(f, range(1000))
```

From another script `start.py` I want to call this and execute with different value against **1000**.

How it is possible to correctly run it with new parameter?

I tried to use import `multy` and run as `os.system('multy.py')` with passing variables, but ot was not successful.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, we use code in `if __name__ == '__main__'` for self-testing.
In your case, I suggest you write related code into a function like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x
def func(num):
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    result = pool.apply_async(f, [10])
    print result.get(timeout=1) 
    print pool.map(f, range(num))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(1000)
```

Then you can import `multy` in another file and invoke `func(yournum)`. It will make your code more readable. Like this:

test.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multy
    multy.func(2)
```

Comment: it doesn't work correctly. After calling multy.func(2) I am getting errors. And execution going in cycles.

Comment: `import multy` doesn't need to be inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard, fwiw. `multy.func(2)` does, of course.

Comment: @user3990145 If there is no more questions, don't forget to accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: Works even for python 3.7 after 7 years of the post (except for the missing parenthesis after the `print`) !